# When a language will be called that it is fully object oriented language?

Tags: java, oop, primitive-types

I referred a tutorial app from Google playstore named AllTech where it is said that java is not a fully object oriented language as it is using PRIMITIVE TYPE.

I would like to know why it is not fully object oriented language as it is using primitive type. Every object oriented language would have primitive type.

So what a language needs to have to be fully object oriented language?

Thanks for your valuable time for looking into this.

Comment: The deep questions always get closed on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't tell you what a fully object oriented language is, but I can give you an example of one to check out: Smalltalk

Comment: I'd recommend checking out list provided in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming . I'm afraid in current form the post is essentially asking for discussion about what OO means - I'd recommend to add exact definition you are interested in so it is clear that existing/new answers actually address your concern instead of talking of what OO is and is not. Also the post may be more on-topic on Programmers SE.

Comment: Additionally you may want to scout interview sites - such questions are quite common in interviews - http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/81148/no-java-not-fully-object-oriented-language-99-9-bcz-if-oo-lang-means-everithing-.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encapsulation.
Inheritance.
Polymorphisim.
Abstraction.

If the language has these attributes, then it can be used to do "full" object-oriented programming.

In Java, primitives are not objects.  It was a conscious design decision in order to improve performance aspects.  For example, there is no abstration around an `int`, nor can you inherit from an `int` and an `int` doesn't encapsulate anything (not even the number of bits it contains), nor can an `int` be polymorphic (although the compiler "helps" out to some degree with auto-boxing and promotion).

So, in some ways a language needs some things to be fully object-oriented, but in other ways it needs to **lack** some things in order to be **only** object-oriented.  Java is fully object-oriented, but it also has primitives.  If it lacked them, then it would be only object-oriented.

People start off learning Java in a hybrid mixed-mode.  They learn to use objects and primitives together.  This has some advantages and some risks.  The risks are that they might program without embracing an object-oriented point of view.  The advantages are that they can leverage the more familiar iterative programming paradigm while they are learning object-orientation.

Real programs rarely get to adhere to only one paradigm over another, but when they do, often they see advantages due to not having to deal with the problematic bits when two approaches collide.

Comment: In addition Java now has Lambda constructs, which are not object-oriented ideas, as they lack stored state, and therefore encapsulation.  Still, they are terribly useful.

Comment: **A PIE** - much easier to follow :)

Comment: @Edwin Buck thanks for your valuable time. Now I have got the clear understanding on this issue. Yes, I searched a lot of interview questions but everyone says different answers. Someone says it is fully object oriented ans someone says it is not as it has primitives. From your answer only I have clearly got the answer.